# How To Wrap Parameters into JSON Object and Pass to the Controller via HttpGet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

Currently I'm creating an Angular web Api Client to pass JSON Object to MVC Web Api Controller. The controller is using **HttpGet** method.

Here's the code for Angular web api Client:

```
    var AngularModule = angular.module('contentApp', []);        

    var parameter = JSON.stringify({ contentid: 1, contenttitle: "Lorem Ipsum" });

    AngularModule.controller('contentCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ApiCall) {
        var result = ApiCall.GetApiCall("http://localhost:8000/api/content/search?" + parameter).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.ContentList = data;
        });
    });

    AngularModule.service('ApiCall', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var result;

        this.GetApiCall = function (EndPoint) {
            result = $http.get(EndPoint).success(function (data, status) {
                result = (data);
            }).error(function () {
                alert("Error Occured");
            });
            return result;
        };
    }]);
```

Here's the code for the Controller (Service):

```
[HttpGet("Search")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Search([System.Web.Http.FromUri] Content list)
    {
        try
        {
            return new ObjectResult(new { status = 1, message = await ContentRepo.Search(new Models.Content())});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I already tried this, but whenever it hit the controller, the object couldn't be read because of different format type (always null).

**My question is** : is that even possible to read JSON object from the URL (QueryString)? and if it's possible, how to handle it?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing your `parameter` object to the data parameter of the `$http.get`?

Please check AngularJS' doc for $http:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Also, you need to use `then` since `$http.get` returns a promise.

```
var AngularModule = angular.module('contentApp', []);        
var parameter = { contentid: 1, contenttitle: "Lorem Ipsum" };

AngularModule.controller('contentCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ApiCall) {
    var result = ApiCall.getApiCall("http://localhost:8000/api/content/search", { data: parameter  }).then(function successCallback(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.ContentList = data;
    }, function errorCallback(errData) {
        alert('Error Occurred');
    });
});

AngularModule.service('ApiCall', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.getApiCall = function (endPoint, data) {
        return $http.get(endPoint, data);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Hi, okay, i'll give it a try, will get back to you for the result :)

Comment: Hi, no luck here, the controller can't receive the object, alias null